# trying to use exact strings for IndexOf within a filterfunction for an array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filter, indexof

I'm currently creating a search function with filter options for an json array:

```
if (ploc != " - " ) {
    var filteredarray7 = filteredarray6.filter(function(orte){
        return orte['Painting Location'].indexOf(ploc) !== -1 ;
    });
} else {
    var filteredarray7 = filteredarray6;
}
```

the variable ploc can be a number from 1-12 or the string " - ", ['Painting Location'] can be strings like "1; 2; 4; 12;", "1" or "3; 5; 12" while each number in this string resembles a category of painting location.

My question: What changes do i need to do, that it returns all objects that include for example 1 in their strings but not those with 10, 11, 12 unless 1 is also part of the string.

Sry for my bad english, it has been a long time since I have written something in a foreign language.

Comment: The good news is you already have a delimiter of `;` for what you store to "Painting Location". You could split that value by `;` then determine if your search variable `ploc` is in the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you better to use regular expressions.

```
return orte['Painting Location'].search(new Regexp('(^|;)\s*' + ploc + '\s*($|;)')) != -1;
```

Or:

```
return !!orte['Painting Location'].match(new Regexp('(^|;)\s*' + ploc + '\s*($|;)'));
```

Read here about [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) in JavaScript.

Comment: You could also do `new RegExp('\\b' + (ploc) + '\\b').test(orte['Painting Location'])` to take advantage of 'word boundaries' in Regex rather than trying to account for whitespace, colons, pipes, etc

Comment: @josh.trow Yes, I agree. The `\b` is the most elegant variant. But it can't check that delimiter is ';'. Anyway, if we sure in this fact, your way is easily.